# ordering page content with php simple dom

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

i have tried numerous ways of approaching this problem, not sure if it can be done. I need to scrape a given html page scraping links  only so what i need to do is order all my links in the order they appear so if i find a h2 link i should then be able to continue on getting all other related links below it before continuing on to the next heading, given some headings will have images as children a read more link or comments and/or other links relating to that story (think of a news website).
As an example

My heading 2

some text

readmore

an image
related links to this story

My Next heading etc

I have tried the following

```
$headings = $html->find('h2 a')//this is in a bigger loop for all other headings but just as an example
foreach($heading as $h){
   echo $h->href; //and what ever else i need, plaintext etc
}
```

trouble with this approach is that i cant find the related links to this heading.

i could search for siblings which i have done but it fails

i have tried getting all links and finding the parent to see if it is a heading and if so store it somewhere else but still the same problem.

Does anyone have any idea how i could tackle this. I am not sure what page i will be given but i think it could be possible to search through the dom until i run into a heading, then keep going until i find the next heading but i cant seem to work through the logic

any ideas would be really appreciated

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

If there is a container that wraps both the h2 and the links, you could iterate those containers and search the h2 and the links inside each container.

I suppose there is not such container.
Another way is taking the whole html string, splitting it by "